# how to create a .so file for a c file which is supported by android-ndk-r5c-windows?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am generating an .so file by using a `gcc` command as

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libMyownMath.so -o libMyownMath.so  MyownMath.o
```

But at `ndk` build I am getting

```
D:/workspace/MyjniMath/obj/local/armeabi/libMyownMath.so: file not recognized: F
ile format not recognized
```

I used this .so file as pre built shared library in my app.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are not cross compiling using the NDK. Try to follow the guidelines provided by Andorid NDK and build the shared library.

Answer (score 0):

What did you use compile?(your compile tool gcc is arm-gcc?)
If your gcc not arm-gcc; you create android project and than jni folder in root directory.
Create Android.mk and c/c++ file after use ndk-build to compile.